# /bin/ftp is failing on a VestaCP linux server, Consider using PASV. 425 Failed to establish connection - how do you fix this?

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

Although the username and password work on the host, when using standard ftp after the connection it stopped working to either put or send files or even do an ls.

This is a VestaCP account = tech support of hosting offers no support. The problem started about a month ago after 5+ years of working. There were no updates by me as the sys admin (which I am not). CentOS 7+ I believe. All support says is there were no updates.

If a send a file it sends as 0 bytes. tmp.txt ftps as 0 bytes. The folder is immaterial, above or within webroot.

```
/Desktop$ ftp hostname.tld
Connected to hostname.tld.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (hostname.tld:me): $account
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> pwd
257 "/"
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
425 Failed to establish connection.
ftp> send tmp.txt
local: tmp.txt remote: tmp.txt
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
425 Failed to establish connection.
ftp>
```

sftp works but with sftp you can only work within webroot whereas ftp generally works in the folder under /home/$account.

I checked in VestaCP but don't see any options to configure ftp, just to create ftp accounts.

Comment: Try typing the command `PASV` after you're connected.  If you get connection success messages instead of failures, try your `ls` and `send` commands.  A decent explanation of the PASV/passive mode in FTP sessions is https://www.jscape.com/blog/active-v-s-passive-ftp-simplified

Comment: ftp> pasv
?Invalid command
ftp>

Comment: pasv failed both upper and lower case after signing in. is there another command that switches the mode? Nothing has been changed in the Firewall or any other server configs since the problem started. I'm not a system admin type and avoid what I don't know.

Comment: The FTP server daemon is suggesting PASV in its responses to you, so it supports passive mode.  Perhaps you're using an FTP client that doesn't support the mode.

Comment: ~/Desktop$ which ftp
/usr/bin/ftp

Comment: A couple months back my Ubuntu desktop pc died (after 14 years). I purchased a new laptop and we installed Linuxmint 20. I just checked a couple other domains I support, both cPanel. FTP to both of them fail as well, same problem. SFTP works but is limited to within webroot. This suggests a problem with the ftp accompanying the linuxmint distribution. Ideas?

Comment: what version of Ubuntu did you have on your desktop?

Comment: I believe Ubuntu  16.04

Comment: Tryp 'passive on' in your ftp-client.

Answer (score 0):

I will succumb to using sftp and SSH to move files that I would ftp above webroot if that is to be their home.